# How to create a voting model in Django?

Tags: django, django-models

I have a model called posts which users can vote up. If the user has voted a post up, he/she can only vote it down after that. How do I implement this system?

My current models looks something like this:

```
class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length = 140)
    user = models.ForeignKey('Auth.user')
    votes = models.IntegerField(default = 0)
```

Is it better to make another model called Vote and link that up to Post, and if so, how do I do it in a way that will scale with a large number of users?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

one way is to create a new model with [unique_together](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/models/options/#unique-together):

```
class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length = 140)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name="user_posts")
    votes = models.IntegerField(default = 0)

    def upvote(self, user):
        try:
            self.post_votes.create(user=user, post=self, vote_type="up")
            self.votes += 1
            self.save()                
        except IntegrityError:
            return 'already_upvoted'
        return 'ok'


    def downvote(self, user):
        try:
            self.post_votes.create(user=user, post=self, vote_type="down")
            self.votes -= 1
            self.save()                
        except IntegrityError:
            return 'already_downvoted'
        return 'ok'

class UserVotes(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name="user_votes")
    post = models.ForeignKey(Post, related_name="post_votes")
    vote_type = models.CharField()


    class Meta:
        unique_together = ('user', 'post', 'vote_type')
```

This way, you create index in your db which makes the search in your table much faster and makes sure that no duplicates come into db.

example:

```
# say, user is logged in
post = Post(user=request.user, 'Awesome post')
post.save()

# another user
user = request.user
# he hits the upvote button, 'post' is Post object
res = post.upvote(user)
if 'ok' in res:
    return HttpResponse('OK')
return HttpResponse('ALREADY_UPVOTED')
```

I didnot test it btw.

Comment: Hello, thanks for the detailed answer. What is the significance of the vote_type = models.CharField()? I mean where is it being used? Edit: Nevermind, I got it, thank you for this!

Comment: `TypeError: __init__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'on_delete'`

Answer (score 3):

The case you explained, says that a `post` can only take `up` votes.

And as you need to hold who has voted up, we need to keep vote and it's user

```
class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length = 140)
    user = models.ForeignKey('Auth.user')

    def votes_count(self):
        return self.votes.all().count()

class Vote(models.Model):
    class Meta:
        unique_together = [('post', 'user')]

    post = models.ForeignKey(Post, related_name='votes')
    user = models.ForeignKey('auth.User')
```

Answer (score 0):

My answer is similar to that of @doniyor's. But, have added some more features :

1. User cant upvote or downvote posts more than once
2. When a post has been downvoted previously, it can be upvoted as well. To ensure this, I add +2 to `Post.votes`. Similarly, the vice-versa also holds.
3. Have used vote_type as a bool variable to save some memory!

```
class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    text = models.TextField()
    votes = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def upvote(self, user):
        try:
            self.vote_set.create(user=user, post=self, vote_type=True)
            self.votes += 1
            self.save()
        except IntegrityError:
            vote = self.vote_set.filter(user=user)
            if vote[0].vote_type == False:
                vote.update(vote_type=True)
                self.votes += 2
                self.save()
            else:
                return 'already_upvoted'
        return 'ok'

    def downvote(self, user):
        try:
            self.vote_set.create(user=user, post=self, vote_type=False)
            self.votes -= 1
            self.save()
        except IntegrityError:
            vote = self.vote_set.filter(user=user)
            if vote[0].vote_type == True:
                vote.update(vote_type=False)
                self.votes -= 2
                self.save()
            else:
                return 'already_downvoted'
        return 'ok'

class Vote(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    post = models.ForeignKey(Post, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    vote_type = models.BooleanField()

    class Meta:
        unique_together = ('user', 'post')
```

Examples:

```
u = User.objects.get(pk=1)
p1 = Post.objects.get(pk=7)

>>> p1.votes
3

>>> p1.upvote(u)
'ok'
>>> p1.votes
4
>>> p1.upvote(u)
'already_upvoted'

>>> p1.downvote(u)
'ok'
>>> p1.votes       
2
>>> p1.downvote(u)
'already_downvoted'
```